# @font-face Issue in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm really having some problems with rendering @font-face CSS and HTML.  The funny thing is that the fonts seems to be loading, but they just look blurry on the page, and then in Safari they are much darker compared to the other browsers.  I'm really disappointed in how things are turning out!

They method I chose to implement was obtained from the CSS Tricks website (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) which is a great resource. It's still not working correctly, and I never have issues viewing any other websites with any of my other browsers.

I've check Cleartype fonts in my Windows 7 and it works. I'm assuming my header CSS is good because the font is rendering, so I'm hoping it's a syntax issue or something simple. Maybe it's also cause I'm using HTML 5?

Here's the page at my testdomain: http://www.richmindonline.com/sampleconversion2.html

I was having probs posting the code here.  There's no CSS file, the styles are internal and inline.

Comment: The problem is that your font is thinner than `1px` and is being rendered at sub-pixel sizes. Scale up your fonts or choose something thicker. I recommend Google Web Fonts (free and includes CSS code): http://www.google.com/webfonts

Comment: Hi Blender, how do I scale up fonts?  Are you meaning just to change the pixel size in the CSS or inline style?  My client wants to keep the exact same font if possible

Comment: Hmm, I've had good luck with Google's fonts. Just make the font-size bigger.

Answer (score 1):

That font you use is just too thin. Also, different browsers will render HTML differently. Some older computers don't even do anti-aliasing. By the way, the text in that link doesn't have anti-aliasing enabled and it actually made me feel weird reading it.

Things to keep in mind when using `@font-face`:

1. Lots of different fonts may look nice but it takes longer to download the page because the fonts have to be rendered as well.
2. Older browsers will not support `@font-face` (especially beware of IE).
3. Design your typesetting keeping in mind of fonts and sizes to use in case font-face fails.

As a rule of thumb, I always choose from one of the standard fonts. They're not too bad.